# How I loop the array of index id and loop one by one in communes and category and location?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, typescript

Here I am working on nodejs typescript API. I am getting the data array of object using map loop. I am getting the "communes" "category" and "location" data from the another API function using issuerId means ID. I am not getting the "communes" "category" and "location". I attached here my code below.

```js
Object.values(premiumValue).map(async(x:any,index:any)=>{
    var issuerId = await Object.values(premiumValue)[index].issuer_id
   
  var Communes = await employerDetail.getSingleProfileType(issuerId, 'Communes')
 
     var category = await employerDetail.getSingleProfileType(issuerId, 'company_type')
     
     var location = await employerDetail.getSingleProfileType(issuerId, 'location')

     Object.assign(values[issuerId], { Communes }, { category }, { location })
     
  })
return Object.values(values)
```

I am getting this kind of data only

```json
[
    {
        "issuer_id": 64,
        "company_name": "Gastro Südtirol",
        "Total_Job": 2
    },
    {
        "issuer_id": 70,
        "company_youtube": "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCB2bOahchY6Hsc_WXnQ-NCw",
        "company_name": "Auto Hofer",
        "Total_Job": 2
    },
    {
        "issuer_id": 72,
        "company_name": "Assimeran GmbH",
        "Total_Job": 2
    }
]
```

I need this kind of data

```json
[
    {
        "issuer_id": 64,
        "company_name": "Gastro Südtirol",
        "Total_Job": 2,
        "Communes": [],
        "category": [],
        "location": [
            {
                "id": 907,
                "location": "brixen"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "issuer_id": 70,
        "company_youtube": "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCB2bOahchY6Hsc_WXnQ-NCw",
        "company_name": "Auto Hofer",
        "Total_Job": 2,
        "Communes": [],
        "category": [],
        "location": [
            {
                "id": 907,
                "location": "brixen"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "issuer_id": 72,
        "company_name": "Assimeran GmbH",
        "Total_Job": 2,
         "Communes": [],
        "category": [],
        "location": [
            {
                "id": 907,
                "location": "brixen"
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
```

But I am getting data without `communes`, `category`, and `location"`. Is there any async/await issue here? How I loop the `communes`, `category`, and `location` data using `issuerId`?

Comment: are you sure the there are properties with keys 'company_type' and 'location' in your employerDetail, maybe thy are part of another object ?

Comment: yes this is part of another api object i am feting with this api data.

Comment: Where does `values` come from? I don't see that set anywhere, but you are assigning to it in the `map()` function. Why even use `map()` if you aren't using the returned array?

Comment: I am getting the data from values variable and in values variable using get sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the shape of the API data and whatever `values` is, here's a guess as to how you could use async/await to pull the data in and format it like you're trying to do. I don't see the need for the `async` `map()` function; you could instead use a traditional `for` loop or `for...of` and wrap everything in an `async` function:

```js
/***** IGNORE ALL OF THIS, JUST SETUP CODE ****/
const api = [
    {
        issuer_id: 64,
        Communes: [],
        company_type: [],
        location: [
            {
                id: 907,
                location: "brixen",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        issuer_id: 70,
        Communes: [],
        company_type: [],
        location: [
            {
                id: 907,
                location: "brixen",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        issuer_id: 72,
        Total_Job: 2,
        Communes: [],
        company_type: [],
        location: [
            {
                id: 907,
                location: "brixen",
            },
        ],
    },
];

const values = {
    64: {
        issuer_id: 64,
        company_name: "Gastro Südtirol",
        Total_Job: 2,
    },
    70: {
        issuer_id: 70,
        company_youtube: "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCB2bOahchY6Hsc_WXnQ-NCw",
        company_name: "Auto Hofer",
        Total_Job: 2,
    },
    72: {
        issuer_id: 72,
        company_name: "Assimeran GmbH",
        Total_Job: 2,
    },
};

/*
 * Ignore this, it just makes the async stuff actually mimic an API call
 */
function sleep() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const time = Math.random() * 500;
        setTimeout(() => resolve(time), time);
    });
}

const employerDetail = {
    getSingleProfileType: async function (issuerId, key) {
        await sleep();
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const foundIndex = api.findIndex((el) => el.issuer_id == issuerId);
            if (foundIndex === -1) {
                reject(`No data in API for issuerId: ${issuerId}`);
            } else {
                resolve(api[foundIndex][key]);
            }
        });
    },
};


/**** THIS IS WHERE YOU WOULD START USING THINGS ***/

async function getAPIData() {
    const apiData = [];
    // I'm just looping through the IDs I see in your output
    for (const issuerId of [64, 70, 72]) {
        const Communes = await employerDetail.getSingleProfileType(issuerId, "Communes");
        const category = await employerDetail.getSingleProfileType(issuerId, "company_type");
        const location = await employerDetail.getSingleProfileType(issuerId, "location");
        apiData.push(Object.assign(values[issuerId], { Communes, category, location }));
    }
    return apiData;
}

async function main() {
    const apiData = await getAPIData();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(apiData, null, 2));
}

main();
```